# Nodejs custom rate limiter takes 200ms per response too much

Tags: node.js, express

I use a custom rate limiter and want to know why it takes more then 200ms for each request. Is this script bad pattern or can I use it in production ? I use redis as store.

```
export const customRedisRateLimiter = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    console.time("concatenation");
    const currentRequestTime = moment();
    // fetch records of the current user using IP address
    const record = await redis.get(req.ip);
    // if no record is found, create a new record for the user and store it in Redis
    if (record == null) {
      const newRecord = [{
        requestTimeStamp: currentRequestTime.unix(),
        requestCount: 1,
      }];
      await redis.set(req.ip, JSON.stringify(newRecord));
      return next();
    }
    // if a record is found, parse its value and calculate the number of requests the user has made within the last window
    const data = JSON.parse(record);
    const windowStartTimestamp = moment().subtract(WINDOW_SIZE_IN_HOURS, 'hours').unix();
    const requestsWithinWindow = data.filter(entry => entry.requestTimeStamp > windowStartTimestamp);
    const totalWindowRequestsCount = requestsWithinWindow.reduce((accumulator, entry) => accumulator + entry.requestCount, 0);
    // if the number of requests made is greater than or equal to the desired maximum, return an error
    if (totalWindowRequestsCount >= MAX_WINDOW_REQUEST_COUNT) {
      return res.status(429).jsend.error(`You have exceeded the ${MAX_WINDOW_REQUEST_COUNT} requests in ${WINDOW_SIZE_IN_HOURS} hrs limit!`);
    }
    // if the number of requests made is less than the allowed maximum, log a new entry
    const lastRequestLog = data[data.length - 1];
    const potentialCurrentWindowIntervalStartTimeStamp = currentRequestTime.subtract(WINDOW_LOG_INTERVAL_IN_HOURS, 'hours').unix();
    // if the interval has not passed since the last request log, increment the counter
    if (lastRequestLog.requestTimeStamp > potentialCurrentWindowIntervalStartTimeStamp) {
      lastRequestLog.requestCount++;
      data[data.length - 1] = lastRequestLog;
    } else {
      // if the interval has passed, log a new entry for the current user and timestamp
      data.push({
        requestTimeStamp: currentRequestTime.unix(),
        requestCount: 1,
      });

    }
    await redis.set(req.ip, JSON.stringify(data));
    console.timeEnd("concatenation");
    return next();
  } catch (error) {
    return next(error);
  }
};
```

From this site: https://blog.logrocket.com/rate-limiting-node-js/

PS: I found that my api calls to redis when I use set or get one takes 100ms. I use it 2x so then I get 200ms. Maybe thats the reason, my redis server is in america and I live in germany and I use a redis test cloud service.

But is this code production ready or are there any bad pattern ?